# Where is the paradox in the halting problem

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Let's say that we have a program ($P$) that takes in a $0$ or a $1$. If a $0$ is inputted the program will loop. If a $1$ is inputted the program will halt. If we assume there is a program that can decide whether a program is going to halt or not ($h$) we can write the statement above

$$h(P(X))$$
$$h(P(0)) = 0$$
$$h(P(1)) = 1$$

Now if we create a program ($R$) that halts if the program loops and loops if the program halts

$$R(h(P(X)))$$
$$h(R(h(P(0)))) = 1$$
$$h(R(h(P(1)))) = 0$$

This new program we can call it $h^\dagger(P(X))$. If we feed this function back into it's self we get
$$h^\dagger(h^\dagger(P(X)))$$

Which is completely decidable for this program
$$h^\dagger(h^\dagger(P(X))) = R(h(R(h(P(X)))))$$
$$h(h^\dagger(h^\dagger(P(0)))) = h(R(h(R(h(P(0)))))) = 0$$
$$h(h^\dagger(h^\dagger(P(1)))) = h(R(h(R(h(P(1)))))) = 1$$

It's clear that
$$h^\dagger(h^\dagger(P(X))) \not = h^\dagger(P(X))$$

which is what the halting problem assumes.

In general $P(X)$ could be any function which means that it is decidable for any function input. In the halting problem, the program takes in the code for $h^\dagger$ and feeds it to its self without giving the first $h^\dagger$ an input, so there is no reason to expect $h^\dagger$ to halt or not because there is no input to make either happen. If you give it an input there is no contradiction. So why is it still undecidable?

Just because the sequence $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ doesn't have a limit why is this enough to conclude that $f(x)$ doesn't exist?

Thanks Josh.

Comment: For starters, if I read this right, $R(h(X))$ will loop and not return anything for any $X$. $h$ will always return a 0 or 1, thus it will always halt, thus $R$ will always loop, so $R(h(X))$ can't have a return value. That's okay when you enclose it as in $h(R(h(\dots)))$, but again doesn't work for $R(h(R(h(\dots))))$.

Comment: @Trevor R(0) will halt whistled R(1) will run forever.

Comment: @Trevor I've surrounded it in h to show that it either loops or halts

Comment: @Trevor so what's the error in my logic? The halting machine cant decide whether or not it's going to halt because it has no input and your feeding it to its self but if you give it one then there is no problem is there?